# Issue while restoring a Database Backup file

Tags: sql, database-backups

I get the below mentioned while restoring a database back-up file to my system. Actually the back-up has been taken in other system and I'm trying to restore that file to my systems' sql server. Could anybody assist me in explaining what the error is and how to rectify? Please...

Error:

"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The database was backed up on a server running version 10.50.1600. That version is incompatible with this server, which is running version 10.00.2531. Either restore the database on a server that supports the backup, or use a backup that is compatible with this server. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)"

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You SQL Server where you want to restore the database is older then the origin.
So to restore this database, you have to use a newer version.

Go to downloads.microsoft.com and get the SQL Express version of the latest, install it on any machine and restore. You can even install on the same machine.
If you cant udpate your SQL Server, you can connect both DB's then and use DTS to move the data back to your "old sql system".

Comment: Thanks for ur guidance... I think it will work if i update my database version as u said.. thanks a lot..